# How can I insert a backslash at the end of a string in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

How can I insert a `\` (backslash) at the end of a string? I am trying this query:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (data) VALUES('testData\ ');
```

But could not insert backslash at the end of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a double slash.  The `\` is an escape character so you'd need to try `\\`.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (data) VALUES('testData\\ ');
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing [SQL Server Mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html) will help.

To change the mode to ignore the black slashes run:
SET sql_mode='NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES';

When you're down with your update just remember to set it back to your regular default mode.